# How to get multiple dates from System-Versioned Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a system versioned table named Archiv.liste and I want to compare 12 dates with the sum of Profit.

Is there a better way to do this than via a UNION?

```
SELECT BranchCO AS Branch --> BAB01
      ,CAST('02.18.2019' AS DATE) AS Stichtag
      ,MONTH(ServiceDate) AS Leistungsmonat
      ,SUM(Profit) AS ProfitSum
FROM archiv.Liste FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '02.18.2019' TL 
GROUP BY  BranchCO,MONTH(ServiceDate)
UNION 
SELECT BranchCO AS Branch --> BAB02
      ,CAST('03.18.2019' AS DATE) AS Stichtag
      ,MONTH(ServiceDate) AS Leistungsmonat
      ,SUM(Profit) AS ProfitSum
FROM archiv.Liste FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '03.18.2019' TL 
GROUP BY  BranchCO,MONTH(ServiceDate)
UNION 
SELECT BranchCO AS Branch --> BAB03
      ,CAST('04.15.2019' AS DATE) AS Stichtag
      ,MONTH(ServiceDate) AS Leistungsmonat
      ,SUM(Profit) AS ProfitSum
FROM archiv.Liste FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '04.15.2019' TL 
GROUP BY  BranchCO,MONTH(ServiceDate)
```

Is there a command like:

```
SELECT * FROM archiv.Liste FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS IN ('02.18.2019','03.18.2019','04.15.2019')
```

Comment: If SYSTEM_TIME is column name then replace FOR by WHERE clause and remove 'AS'. Like 
`SELECT * FROM archiv.Liste WHERE SYSTEM_TIME IN ('02.18.2019','03.18.2019','04.15.2019')`

Comment: Explain definitely, what you actually want.

Comment: Why don't you query the *history* table? The most important feature of SQL's (the language's) temporal tables is that the history is always visible as a table, even if the history table name isn't specified

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:
   SELECT * FROM archiv.Liste FOR SYSTEM_TIME CONTAINED IN ('02.18.2019','03.18.2019','04.15.2019')

Comment: `CONTAINED IN` accepts only two parameters, start date and end date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make the date filter after gets all the row versions from both the Temporal and History table (by `ALL` keyword). You can change `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns with your period start and end columns names.

```
SELECT 
      BranchCO AS Branch --> BAB01
     ,CAST(StartTime AS DATE) AS Stichtag
     ,MONTH(ServiceDate) AS Leistungsmonat
     ,SUM(Profit) AS ProfitSum
FROM archiv.Liste
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
WHERE 
    (StartTime <= '02.18.2019' AND EndTime > '02.18.2019')
    OR  (StartTime <= '03.18.2019' AND EndTime > '03.18.2019')
    OR  (StartTime <= '04.15.2019' AND EndTime > '04.15.2019')
```